# concat() with select query?

Tags: mysql

I need to use a concat function which has an argument returned by select query like this

```
CONCAT(classification_version.NAME,' ',
(select x.NAME,min(DATEDIFF(e.SEND_DATE, x.OPTENTION_DATE)) 
AS DT_DIFF 
from classification_version x inner join classification_element y 
on x.id_project=y.ID_PROJECT inner join email e 
on x.id_project=e.ID_PROJECT_AMENDMENT
where  
y.ID_PROJECT=project.id and y.ID_COMPANY=company.id 
and e.SEND_DATE>x.OPTENTION_DATE  group by e.id,e.SEND_DATE 
order by e.SEND_DATE ASC)
```

This is only a part of a query that I have. I need to return min(datediff) because I need the corresponding name value only. But it throws an error that Operand should contain 1 column(s). I cannot use inner queries for the select statement as project.id and company.id will not be available to me then. IS there any way to solve this?

Comment: `This is only a part of a query that I have` Do you really expect any effort on our part if this isn't the entire query?

Comment: if you can link a sqlfiddle here then you can get help quick also it will be helpful to others to understand your problem in better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your SQL check it once.

```
SELECT CONCAT(q1.NAME,' ',DT_DIFF) FROM 
(SELECT x.NAME,MIN(DATEDIFF(e.SEND_DATE, x.OPTENTION_DATE)) 
AS DT_DIFF 
FROM classification_version x INNER JOIN classification_element y
ON x.id_project=y.ID_PROJECT INNER JOIN email e 
ON x.id_project=e.ID_PROJECT_AMENDMENT
WHERE  
y.ID_PROJECT=project.id AND y.ID_COMPANY=company.id 
AND e.SEND_DATE>x.OPTENTION_DATE  GROUP BY e.id,e.SEND_DATE 
ORDER BY e.SEND_DATE ASC) AS q1
```

Thank you.